# Geoserver WMS SQL VIEW parameters with accents

Tags: geoserver

I'm getting this error when I pass latin words (with accents and "ç") as parameter to a SQL View layer.

> Rendering process failed 
>   java.io.IOException
>   null
>   Invalid value for parameter NOME_IMOVEL

Look this error on log:

> Invalid value for parameter NOME_IMOVEL
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value ARAÃUAI does not match ^[\w\d\sáàéíóúÁÀÉÍÓÚçÇ]+$

I sent "NOME_IMOVEL:ARAÇUAI".

Did anyone had this issue before? Is there any workaround?

Comment: I think you can solve it in the same way as for a CQL filter

Comment: Sorry, I didn't saw this question. I'll do an workaround as suggested by @rainer. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

haven't had that error yet, but i'd recommend not using any accents. they are often causing errors

maybe try using ASCII coding for accents, if you can't do it without them

Comment: Thx. I decided to remove them from the url and use a "translate" to replace them on the comparison.